# WAV file modifier using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mono, wav, wave

I wrote a simple Python program to read a wave file and after changing it store it as a new file.

```
import codecs, wave

#convert a number to its two's complemented value (For positive it is equal itself)
def convert_to_twos(value, wid_len=16):
    if value < 0 :
        value = value + (1 << wid_len)
    return value

#receive the value of a two's complemented number.
def twos_back_value(value, wid_len=16):
    if value & (1 << wid_len -1):
        value = value - (1 << wid_len)
    return value

#opening files
input_file = wave.open(r"<address of input wave file>", 'r')
output_file = wave.open(r"<an address for output wave file>", 'w')

#Get input file parameters and set them to the output file after modifing the channel number.
out_params = [None, None, None, None, None, None]
in_params = input_file.getparams()
out_params[0] = 1 # I want to have a mono type wave file in output. so I set the channels = 1
out_params[1] = in_params[1] #Frame Width
out_params[2] = in_params[2] #Sample Rate
out_params[3] = in_params[3] #Number of Frames
out_params[4] = in_params[4] #Type
out_params[5] = in_params[5] #Compressed or not
output_file.setparams(out_params)

#reading frames from first file and storing in the second file
for frame in range(out_params[2]):
    value = int(codecs.getencoder('hex')(input_file.readframes(1))[0][:4], 16) #converting first two bytes of each frame (let assume each channel has two bytes frame length) to int (from byte string).
    t_back_value = twos_back_value( value ,out_params[1]*8)
    new_value = int(t_back_value * 1)
    new_twos = convert_to_twos(new_value, out_params[1]*8)
    to_write = new_twos.to_bytes((new_twos.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
    output_file.writeframes(to_write)


#closing files
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

The problem is when I run the above program and play the output file I can hear only noise and nothing else! (While I expect the same file only in one channel mode!)

**Update:**

I got something weird. Based on the documentation, the function `readframes(n)` *Reads and returns at most n frames of audio, as a string of bytes*. So I expect only hex values in return by this function. But in real I can see some weird non-hex values:

```
read_frame = input_file.readframes(1)
print (read_frame)
print (codecs.getencoder('hex')(read_frame)[0])
print ("")
```

above code, in a for loop return this:

```
b'\xe3\x00\xc7\xf5'
b'e300c7f5'

b'D\xe8\xa1\xfd'
b'44e8a1fd'

b'\xde\x08\xb2\x1c'
b'de08b21c'

b'\x17\xea\x10\xe9'
b'17ea10e9'

b'{\xf7\xbc\xf5'
b'7bf7bcf5'

b'*\xf6K\x08'
b'2af64b08'
```

As you see there are some non-hex values in the `read_frame`! (*, }, D, ... for example). What are these?

Comment: What modification to the WAV file are you trying to achieve? i.e. for each frame what should the output be?

Comment: @MartinEvans I want to change the RMS (Root Mean Square) of WAV files. It's a part of a psychology experiment project. For example I want to have a new version of the previous file with a RMS half the first file.

Comment: @MartinEvans Check update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you are seeing are the four bytes for each frame, namely two bytes for the first channel and two bytes for the second channel. For a mono WAV, you would only see two bytes.

The following approach should get you going on the correct path. You need to use Python's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) library to convert your binary frame values into signed integers. You can then manipulate them as required. For my example I simply multiply by 2/3:

```
import wave
import codecs
import struct

#opening files
input_file = wave.open(r"sample.wav", 'rb')
output_file = wave.open(r"sample_out.wav", 'wb')

#Get input file parameters and set them to the output file after modifing the channel number.
in_params = list(input_file.getparams())

out_params = in_params[:]
out_params[0] = 1
output_file.setparams(out_params)

nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname = in_params
format = '<{}h'.format(nchannels)

#reading frames from first file and storing in the second file
for index in range(nframes):
    frame = input_file.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack(format, frame)
    value = data[0]     # first (left) channel only
    value = (value * 2) // 3    # apply a simple function to each value
    output_file.writeframes(struct.pack('<h', value))

#closing files
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Note, processing a wave file a frame at a time like this will be painfully slow. It could be sped up by reducing the number of calls to `writeframes`.

`format` holds the format needed to unpack the binary values. For a 2-channel WAV file this will contain 4 bytes. `format` will then be configured as `<hh` which means using `struct.unpack` will result in two fields, each containing the integer representation of each channel. So four bytes becomes a list of two integers, one for each channel.

Comment: Thank you dear Martin, but did you tried it? Unfortunately I have a noisy output still. I mean I can hear noise only! (Input file is ok)

Comment: Yes I tested it on a stereo WAV file. It produced a mono WAV file with the amplitude reduced. The file size was halved. I also recreated the noise you were getting with your version.

Comment: Does it make any problem if I replace `nframe` with a short number to test the program?(100,000 for example). In both `for` loop and `out_params` variable.

Comment: I just tried with `nframes // 3` and it worked fine.

Comment: May I know what audio player you are using?

Comment: And, if possible, May I have the sample input file please? (if so, my email is: ebr.ghasemi @ gmail). Thank you so much.

Comment: If I print `in_param` for my test file, it shows `[2, 2, 44100, 182522, 'NONE', 'not compressed']`.

Comment: Weird! Mine is `[2, 2, 44100, 9692592, 'NONE', 'not compressed']`! So there is no problem with that. May I know which version of Python, which Audio File player and Which Operation system do you have? Mine: *Python 3.5 - KMPlayer - Win7Ultimate64Bit!*

Comment: 3.4.3 Anaconda 2.3.0 (32-bit), and the output WAV played fine in Windows Media player and VNC. I'm on Windows7 64bit. I am assuming your input WAV plays ok. Have you copied the sample exactly without modification?

Comment: The only change that I did on your code, is replacing file names. (`sample.wav` replaced with my file name.). I think I need to down-grade my Python version to 3.4.3 Anaconda.

Comment: Use a full path to your output file, does the date on your output file change after the script is run?

Comment: Yes, the path is okay. I replaced `sample.wav` with `1.wav`. And `1.wav` is  in the same directory of `test.py` (This script). And, yes, after running the script, it successfully create `sample_out.wav`. I print the params of this new file, and it is: `[1, 2, 44100, 9692592, 'NONE', 'not compressed']`. It seems okay too! My output file size is half the input size (18.4 and 36.9)! I don't know what is the origin of problem!

Comment: Is it possible to send me your sample file?

Comment: Okay, weird! It's okay with your sample file. :( thank you for your time. If you let me, I marked your answer tomorrow. :)

Comment: The line `value = data[0]`, should not be `value = data[0] * 256 +  data[1]` for files with _Sample Width = 2_? I think for this files, each channel has 2 bytes length in each frame. No?

Comment: data[0] already holds both bytes for the first channel. The struct.unpack did that.

Comment: If your byte ordering is different you could try removing the `<`

Comment: Excuse me, this is my last question :). Shouldn't we change the values before multiplying by 2/3 for example? (Because negetive values of  the frames are two's complemented). I mean as some of them are two's complemented, the output seems not to be exactly 2/3 of input. Am I wrong again?

Comment: Not needed as at that point you are working with Python signed integers. The struct.pack converts it back to a 2 byte binary.